# Is it possible to load image from GKAchievementDescription?

Tags: gamekit, achievements

I'm using this method to load all achievements description.

```
[GKAchievementDescription loadAchievementDescriptionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(NSArray *descriptions, NSError *error) {
     CCLOG(@"achivements loaded");
     if (error != nil) {
         NSLog(@"Error %@", error);

 } else {
     if (descriptions != nil){
         CCLOG(@"nb %i",descriptions.count);
         for (GKAchievementDescription* a in descriptions) {
             CCLOG(@"image %@ %@ %@", a.title, a.achievedDescription, a.image);
             [achievementsDescDictionary setObject: a forKey: a.identifier];
         }
     } else {
         CCLOG(@"descriptions empty");
     }
     }
 }];
```

I always get a.image = null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't load images from Game Center.

Just add your achievements Images into your project and use this method with GKAchievementHandler

```
- (void)notifyAchievementTitleAndImage:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString *)message withImage:(UIImage *)image
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can't load the images from game center then what about to create a plist file for mapping "achievements-images"? I used this technique for my game which is similar to 3-in-row to define various types of blocks